# Get Groups of Customers Names based on their Title

Tags: sql

Get the Count of Contact's person by their title. (Table: Customers) below:

[image]

Now, below SQL code will get group counts, but I want to add also the names associated with each group if possible please:

```
SELECT ContactTitle, Count(ContactTitle) FROM Customers
GROUP BY ContactTitle;
```

**Database**: This is from NorthWind database.

Comment: What names? company names?

Comment: @ReutSchremer. I would like to associate with each group ContactName (which is customer name).

Comment: @ReutSchremer. Some groups might have more than 1 customer.

Comment: What about 
`SELECT ContactTitle,ContactName, Count(ContactTitle) over (partition by ContactTitle) FROM Customers
`
?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...) [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT ContactTitle, ContactName, Count(ContactTitle) over (partition by ContactTitle) as usersCoun FROM Customers;
```